# Show that this Linear Operator is Self-Adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=M_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ and Let $P\in V$ be some invertible real matrix.
>
> We define the operator $T:V\to V$ by: $\ \forall A\in V,\ T(A)=P^{-1}AP$.
>
> The adjoint operator $T^*$ w.r.t the standard inner product $\left<A,B\right>=tr(B^tA)$ is given by $\forall A\in V, T^*(A)=\left(P^{-1}\right)^{t}AP^t$.
>
> What is a necessary and sufficient condition for $T$ to be self-adjoint?

I can show that it is sufficient for $P$ to be self-adjoint, and that it is necessary for $P$ to be normal. But I am stuck in showing that one of these is **both** necessary and sufficient..

Comment: As it turns out: self-adjoint is sufficient and normal is necessary, but neither is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Do you know that every self adjoint operator admits an orthonormal eigenbasis with real eigenvalues (aka the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators) and vice versa? Try to compute the eigenvalues of your operator.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom With the help of your hint I concluded that P being self-adjoint is both necessary and sufficient, but this contradicts your comment so I'm a bit confused XD

Comment: @Evan the other possibility is that $A$ is skew-adjoint, i.e. $A^T = -A$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I should have noticed that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that if $P^{-1}AP = Q^{-1}AQ$ for all matrices $A$, then it follows that
$$
A(PQ^{-1}) = (PQ^{-1})A
$$
for all matrices $A$.  It follows that $PQ^{-1}$ is a multiple of the identity matrix.